# Multiplying complex matrices in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm trying to port a code from matlab to C. In order to convert this line to C:

```
A = E*[SOLS' ; ones(1,10 ) ];
```

Where,

```
>>size(SOLS)
```

ans =

```
10     3
```

and:

```
>> size(E)
```

ans =

```
 9     4
```

SOLS is a complex single matrix and E is a real single matrix and A should be a complex single matrix of size 9x10.

I replaced `A = E*[SOLS' ; ones(1,10 ) ];` with

```
for i=1:9
  for j=1:10
    A1(i,j)=E(i,1)*SOLS(j,1))+E(i,2)*SOLS(j,2))+E(i,3)*SOLS(j,3))+E(i,4);
   end
end
```

The complex resultant matrix elements have the same real part as A but a different imaginary part.

```
>> real(A)=real(A1)
imag(A) and `imag(A1)` are different.
```

What caused this difference? How to convert the matlab command correctly to C?

Here are examples of matrices:

```
    E =

    0.2248         0         0         0
   -0.4487   -0.1632   -0.1955    0.6355
    0.4379   -0.0651   -0.1032   -0.0754
   -0.4008    0.3513    0.2707   -0.5936
   -0.2294   -0.7853   -0.3290   -0.4648
    0.0385    0.2623   -0.6363   -0.0978
   -0.5716    0.0851    0.0943    0.0587
    0.1160   -0.3911    0.5964    0.0947
    0.0363   -0.0039   -0.0092   -0.0018
```

and

```
    SOLS =

   1.0e+02 *

  -0.2410 + 0.0000i   2.3741 + 0.0000i  -0.0646 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0113 - 0.0046i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0113 + 0.0046i
  -0.0028 + 0.0000i  -0.0114 + 0.0000i  -0.0038 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0024 - 0.0043i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0024 + 0.0043i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0007 - 0.0191i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.0007 + 0.0191i
  -0.0080 + 0.0000i   0.0064 + 0.0000i   0.0108 + 0.0000i
  -0.7289 + 0.0000i   4.9347 + 0.0000i   0.3841 + 0.0000i
```

Comment: You said you are converting it from Matlab to C. The`for` loop isn't in C. What are you actually trying to do? I can't see any conversion to C.

Comment: It is trivial to convert for loops from Matlab to C. I want to test it in Matlab first then write it in C

Comment: Your question does not state that this is what you are trying to do. You state that you are trying to convert from Matlab to C. Your question states one thing but you are actually trying to do another and this is makes the question confusing. Please remember that you have to write in a way so that people not familiar with your project would understand it. Please see [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MATLAB, `SOLS'` performs the complex conjugate transpose operation, that is element {i,j} becomes element {j,i} and its value is transformed as `a + 1i*b --> a -1i*b`. To retain the phase of your complex values use `SOLS.'` as follows:

```
A = E*[SOLS.' ; ones(1,10 ) ];
```

In addition this is how you want to perform the loop (translating of course to proper C):

```
for i=1:size(E,1)
  for j=1:size(SOLS,1)
        A1(i,j)=0;
        for k = 1:size(SOLS,2)
            A1(i,j)= A1(i,j) + E(i,k)*SOLS(j,k);
        end
        A1(i,j)= A1(i,j) + E(i,k+1);
   end
end
```

Then

```
A1 - A

ans =

   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: You could save the assignment A=0 before the inner loop but you can do that when you work it all out in C...