# Confusion with complex numbers manipulation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, complex-numbers

I'm confused with the manipulation of complex numbers in MATLAB. 
I have `EE` is a `9x4` real matrix which I want to multiply with a complex `10x3` matrix `SOLS`. The nitial code in Matlab is:

```
Evec= EE*[SOLS' ; ones(1,10 ) ];
```

This line is normally equivalent to:

```
SOLSt=SOLS';

  for i=1:9
    for j=1:10
    Evec(i,j)=EE(i,1)*SOLSt(1,j)+EE(i,2)*SOLSt(2,j)+EE(i,3)*SOLSt(3,j)+EE(i,4);
    end
  end
```

Why the above loop dosen't give the same result as:

```
   for i=1:9
    for j=1:10
    RE(i,j)=EE(i,1)*real(SOLSt(1,j))+EE(i,2)*real(SOLSt(2,j))+EE(i,3)*real(SOLSt(3,j))+EE(i,4);
    IM(i,j)=EE(i,1)*imag(SOLSt(1,j))+EE(i,2)*imag(SOLSt(2,j))+EE(i,3)*imag(SOLSt(3,j))+EE(i,4);
    end
    end
    Evec=complex(RE,IM);
```

When I did `SOLSt=SOLS'`we did a conjugate transpose, that's OK. Now, for the multiplication of the real matrix `EE` with the complex matrix `SOLSt` which is the conjugate transpose of `SOLS`. Mathematically, it gives an imaginary number which real part refers to the product of `EE(i)` and `Real(SOLSt(i))` and its imaginary part refers to the product of `EE(i)` and `imag(SOLSt(i))`
which is translated by the second version mentioned above, but this gives a different result from the first version which is also the multiplication of `EE(i)` with `SOLSt(i)`..What I understood from this difference in results is that when i write `EE(i)*SOLSt(i)` Matlab dosen't perform exactly the product of real part and imaginary parts.
I don't want to use `SOLS'.`, I just want to find the same result with the initial command `Evec= EE*[SOLS' ; ones(1,10 ) ];` not using `.'` in a different way

Comment: possible duplicate of [Complex and real matrice multiplication in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29232340/complex-and-real-matrice-multiplication-in-matlab)

Comment: It is my old question, i just haven't found a solution yet. I thought the problem concerned only the conjugate transpose matrix. But even when I corrected it, I didn't get the wanted result. The problem is in the multiplication itself

Comment: I can't see the difference in these two questions. Unless you clarify what the difference between these two is, I'm voting to close.

Comment: I just edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line where you complex part of `Evec`, you inluded `EE(i,4)` in the sum. This shouldn't be there as it only exists in the real part of the solution. Things work fine if you use this instead:

```
IM(i,j)=EE(i,1)*imag(SOLSt(1,j))+EE(i,2)*imag(SOLSt(2,j))+EE(i,3)*imag(SOLSt(3,j));
```